# What additive or method can be used to give Graphene better fracture resistance?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

So I am a student and we were charged with designing and making a working model of a car. My car of choice was an electric one, with a graphene-titanium frame, and that brings me to my problem. I've been doing research on graphene and its properties when it comes to utilizing it in any structure. I've found that it has remarkable strength, that is it has great resistance to deformation. But a caveat is that it has poor toughness, or fracture resistance. Since this must be a working model, and since we have to consider possible problems and constraints, I need to know if anyone has any extra research regarding additives or methods in which graphene can have higher toughness, since a car crash can be devastating and could render the titanium all on its own if the graphene can't do much.
(link to Berkeley lab article: https://newscenter.lbl.gov/2016/02/08/graphene-is-strong-but-is-it-tough/)

Comment: Probably better suited to the Chemistry site?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that but most were inconclusive so I thought "Why not give this site a try?"

Comment: Do you use the graphene in some kind of a matrix, like a polymer or resin?

Comment: Polymer, yes, with some overlaying sheets to increase structural integrity, but even then the toughness is a problem.

Comment: I used to be a polymer development manager. What polymer are you using?

Comment: Does a simple graphene sheet count? It isn't traditionally considered a polymer because it doesn't really have extra fibers or particles added but we were told it basically is. But yeah, just a simple graphene sheet added to the outer layers of the frame, as our group decided on.

Comment: I don't think there's any pixie dust out there to 'magically' improve the tensile strength of pure graphene. I was thinking more along the lines of a composite, where a polymer or resin embeds the graphene. Graphene incidentally **IS** a polymer, albeit an unusual one.

Comment: Wait, you want to improve the crash resistance of a titanium car with a single-atom-thick graphene layer?

Comment: That’s what makes graphene a wonder material, it is usually stand-alone, so that’s why our team chose it haha.

Comment: But we were also planning on layering it with multiple sheets, and in our research we found that even a small layer of graphene can improve integrity of a structure quite significantly, quite amazing if you ask me.